# Implementing One-to-One unidirectional association in Java

Tags: java, associations, uml

How to implement One-to-one unidirectional association in Java (without ORM). I think bidirectional is possible. Association means both classes (say Part and PartNumber) need to exist independently, one to one means only one part number for one part and vice versa, unidirectional means part should know about part number but opposite. Now how Part number will know whether it has been assigned already. If we sacrifice independent existence of PartNumber then its composition.

Comment: Are you telling us or asking us? <--- Notice how a question ends with a question mark. You should try it.

Comment: Oh sure next time will take care.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this as either a unidirectional or a bidirectional association.  Either will work.  Ensuring that the 1-to-1 property is invariant maintained can be done in various ways:

- In the bidirectional case, have the setters use the forward or reverse link to ensure that the object at the other end is not already related, and maybe break that relationship.
- In the unidirectional case, by removing the ability to set a Part's `PartNumber` or a `PartNumber`'s `Part`; e.g. have the `Part` create its own `PartNumber` in its constructor.

Another alternative is to make `PartNumber` a "value-based class", and always use `PartNumber.equals(Object)` to test for equality.

Comment: Agreed Stephen with the first part but about second part I am confused wont it become become composition (As Part number remains internal to Part and get destroyed with Part)?

Comment: Possibly yes.  But does it matter?

Answer (score -2):

I found an implementation here: http://programmersthing.blogspot.in/2017/06/java-concepts.html

```
    1.Customer Class :
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Customer {
        private String name;
        ArrayList<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();

        public Customer(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public ArrayList<Order> getOrders() {
            return orders;
        }

        public void addOrder(Order order) {
            orders.add(order);
        }

    }

    2.LineItem  Class :

    public class LineItem {
        private int quantity;
        Product products;

        public LineItem(int quantity, Product products) {
            this.quantity = quantity;
            this.products = products;
        }

        public double calculateLineItemCost() {
            return (quantity * products.calculatePriceAfterDiscount());
        }

        public int getQuantity() {
            return quantity;
        }

        public Product getProducts() {
            return products;
        }

    }
```

Comment: This "answer" is nothing but a **code quote** from an external source. Yes; you added the link to the source, but just **dumping** some code from somewhere is for sure not an **answer** in the spirit of this community.

Comment: I do not think above code provides required relation with mentioned constraints.

Comment: Based on above discussions I conclude that one to one unidirectional relationship can not be implemented in Java (Composition is possible). In a sense such relationship is itself contradiction as second object can not obey the constraint without knowing with how many first objects its connected (which is impossible for it due to unidirectional navigation). Please comment if this is not the correct understanding..